# How many loops is jQuery doing with chaining?

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have this jQuery code:

```
$('.popUp').width(300).height(300).text('Hi!').fadeIn(1000);
```

Let's say `.popUp` has 50 elements. `width(300)` will loop through these 50 elements and apply the appropriate property value.

My question is: What happens then? When it's `height(300)` time to start running, does it start all over again (new loop) and apply the property values again?

What is going on in the background? In this particular example, will there be 4 loops (because there are 4 functions) or 1 loop where each of these functions will be applied in one go?

Comment: AFAIK When you use selector like `$('#popUp')` jquery takes only one element that is with id `popup`. Not 50 elements inside it.

Comment: You probably meant `.popUp` instead

Comment: Yes, .popUp, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, jQuery will loop over all of the elements and set the width and then loop over them again and set the height.

In the source for the [jquery's access function](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/305f193aa57014dc7d8fa0739a3fefd47166cd44/src/core/access.js#L45-L53) you can see where that loop is run on each element that is selected.

```
if ( fn ) {
    for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
        fn(
            elems[ i ], key, raw ?
            value :
            value.call( elems[ i ], i, fn( elems[ i ], key ) )
        );
    }
}
```

The access method is what's eventually called for things like setting height and width.

```
// Multifunctional method to get and set values of a collection
// The value/s can optionally be executed if it's a function
```

I came across this by stepping through the call with a debugger by doing the following in the console.

```
var height = $.fn.height;
$.fn.height = function() {
    debugger;
    return height.apply(this, arguments);
}
```